# Multiple threads writes multiple files same time - it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, multithreading, io, locking

In our WCF service the clients can upload file chunks. Several clients uploads files, some clients uploads on multiple threads. To serialize file access on server side we created a dictionary to lock the given file access. When a thread wants to access a file for writing - checks this dictionary if it contains or not the given filename. If it contains - it signs that a thread is currently access the file. To release the lock we simple removes the filename from the dictionary.

public class FileUploader
{
    private static readonly Dictionary FileStreams = new Dictionary(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

```
public void SaveChunk(String storagePath, File file, Int64 currentPos, Byte[] chunk)
{
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(OpenFileStream(storagePath)))
    {
        try
        {
            SaveChunk(writer, currentPos, chunk);
        }
        finally
        {
            writer.Close();
            RemoveLock(storagePath);
        }
    }
}

private Stream OpenFileStream(String fullFileName)
{
    Stream result = null;
    lock (FileStreams)
    {
        while (FileStreams.ContainsKey(fullFileName))
        {
            Monitor.Wait(FileStreams);
        }
        result = System.IO.File.Open(fullFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        FileStreams[fullFileName] = true;
    }
    return result;
}

private void RemoveLock(String fileName)
{
    lock (FileStreams)
    {
        FileStreams.Remove(fileName);
        Monitor.Pulse(FileStreams);
    }
}
```

Somehow we spmetime got an error message:

> The process cannot access the file '\ourstorage\folder\a_file_name.zip'
>   because it is being used by another process.
>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

But we cannot see why. It seems the code is correct, and wont access two threads same file same time. Any idea?

Comment: The most likely candidates are anti-virus, or you are running more than one process (i.e. web farm or web garden).

Comment: Thanks. This code runs for years, and only a couple of weeks the error message appears. May the antivirus behaviour has been changed. My responsibility is only the code.

Comment: Are you running a web farm or a web garden?

Comment: No. Only one WCF service is running, and do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You write with different threads in the same file. You have to check in every thread, if you are already writing in this file.

Comment: I do. This is why I use Monitor and lock. Or how do you mean?